# 403 error in calling DerivativeApi of Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge, unauthorized

**Autodesk Forge**'s **DerivativeApi** is not working with my client id and secret. Apis returns unauthorized error,  **{ statusCode: 403, statusMessage: 'Unauthorized’ }**.

But they works with the sample's client id/secret (from  https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/dmSample.js).

Is there any limitation for calling DerivativeApi (for translating) with free account? or should I do something?

Here is the sample code...

```
var ForgeSDK = require('forge-apis');

// TODO - insert your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET
// Below id/secret from the sample are working, but mine is not.
 var CLIENT_ID = 'wmizntnpzCJxPGF9lxsIiTZGbGO2cJqw',
   CLIENT_SECRET = 'g5IPJwvhOHcrdbFy';

var derivativesApi = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi();

// Initialize the 2-legged oauth2 client
var oAuth2TwoLegged = new ForgeSDK.AuthClientTwoLegged(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
  ['data:write', 'data:read', 'bucket:read', 'bucket:update', 'bucket:create'], true);

function defaultHandleError(err) {
  console.error('\x1b[31m Error:', err, '\x1b[0m');
}

oAuth2TwoLegged.authenticate().then(function (credentials) {
  console.log("**** Got Credentials", credentials);
  derivativesApi.getFormats({}, oAuth2TwoLegged, oAuth2TwoLegged.getCredentials()).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  }, defaultHandleError);
}, defaultHandleError);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, and extremely important, **NEVER** share your ID & Secret. If the above is your correct one, please create a new **secret** (to invalidate this).

Now the ID & Secret should work for any sample, just make sure you activated the APIs for it. On your app, select `Model Derivative API` on the screen, if not available, [please review this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/not-all-apis-are-available-my-forge-app).

Finally, the code sample above is not actually calling Model Derivative. If so, note that files uploaded into one account are not accessible from other accounts, and URNs are unique.